# Syntax to Create User On Another Server via DB Link

Tags: oracle, dblink

I'd like to create a user on another server using a db link. Is this possible? (Lets assume I have permission)

Here's the syntax for creating a user on the local server

```
create user TEST_USER 
identified by TEST_USER_PW 
default tablespace USERS 
temporary tablespace TEMP;
```

How could it be done with a db link?

Thank you (Feel free to migrate this to DBA if it's off topic)

Edit: Haki brought up that DDL operations are not allowed on a remote database. I'll post an alternative once I find one.

Comment: i dont think you can execute DDL via dblink. may be if you create a function in the other database and just execute it via the dblink.

Comment: It could be done with Java stored procedure which connects to remote DB and do whatever you want there.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I'm looking into this alternative now. Do you know of any resources on hand that could be helpful?

Comment: @haki It appears you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute DDL on over a database link using [DBMS_UTILITY.EXEC_DDL_STATEMENT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_util.htm#i1002666):

```
begin
    dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement@myself(
        'create user TEST_USER 
        identified by TEST_USER_PW 
        default tablespace USERS 
        temporary tablespace TEMP');
end;
/
```

Comment: This is correct, however potentially dangerous solution. I ended up going with haki's solution. Thank you for the input.